# Page won't scroll to an id when its hash is already in the url, when using ui-router (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

When using ui-router for angularjs, I can't get hash-id linking working as expected.  If the URL already has the hash I want to jump to in it (ie whatever.com/#/route1#des1) and I click an anchor tag with a link to #des1, then the link will not work and the page will not scroll down to the div with that id.  You can easily cause this with the plunker below by clicking a link, scrolling back to the top, and then clicking the same link.

Please see the plunker with the issue: https://plnkr.co/edit/b8MJ2b37z0nYG0qbsy29?p=preview

Is there a way to allow ui-router to jump to a id that it has just been to?  Is this just an issue with ui-router?  It doesn't seem to exist when ui-router is not used (see http://plnkr.co/edit/iz1SseMqLISlWZ6fOSKC?p=preview).

```
<a ui-sref="route1({'#': 'des1'})">Jump to P1</a>
<br>
<a ui-sref="route1({'#': 'des2'})">Jump to P2</a>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="des1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ornare vulputate nisl eget sagittis. Sed dapibus leo sed ultricies viverra. Maecenas aliquet euismod nibh in elementum. Sed eu augue eget odio luctus lacinia ac non augue. Nunc luctus iaculis tellus sit amet vestibulum. Nunc at purus felis. Cras felis tellus, consequat at tellus eget, pretium efficitur quam. Curabitur sapien nunc, lobortis a metus ut, vehicula aliquet nisi.
Aliquam pellentesque eu turpis in interdum. Nulla porttitor urna magna, a aliquam justo lobortis dignissim. Donec tincidunt, magna vel interdum bibendum, velit sem vulputate ipsum, iaculis volutpat est arcu id orci. Nulla venenatis ipsum non interdum pharetra. Nullam mattis, orci at pretium suscipit, lacus lacus sagittis dui, sit amet sollicitudin sem ipsum non enim. Aenean pulvinar leo risus, vel imperdiet nulla eleifend et. Duis vel neque sagittis, dapibus arcu et, interdum arcu. Proin at molestie elit. Vivamus aliquam porta urna et tincidunt. Integer eu odio risus. Suspendisse ornare magna ac erat maximus, quis faucibus lectus eleifend. Aliquam pellentesque sagittis lacus sed tempor. Praesent aliquet tellus non nunc euismod varius. Donec pharetra cursus nunc, nec commodo erat malesuada nec. Nam ac facilisis lorem, eget vestibulum mauris. Nam nunc odio, tempor at condimentum et, pellentesque vitae erat.
Donec mollis dolor fringilla sapien condimentum, non ultrices tortor blandit. Aenean vel massa ipsum. Ut leo nisl, vehicula nec mi elementum, varius lacinia risus. Vestibulum metus nibh, hendrerit non velit sit amet, posuere hendrerit nunc. Aenean ut felis in nisi convallis interdum. Vestibulum posuere, nulla vitae bibendum elementum, dui metus auctor ante, et ullamcorper leo turpis quis tellus. Phasellus condimentum tellus quis posuere tempus. Fusce faucibus laoreet turpis a hendrerit. Phasellus tempor consectetur urna. In dictum turpis et ligula dictum, nec placerat mi elementum. Sed interdum, eros ut finibus elementum, elit quam auctor dui, et maximus orci justo commodo tortor. Maecenas eu efficitur massa.
Vivamus at eros vel magna facilisis lacinia quis vel est. Vivamus et quam ligula. Vestibulum hendrerit scelerisque enim, eu dapibus dui pulvinar a. Vestibulum mollis tortor sit amet tempor pharetra. Nullam facilisis leo sit amet justo auctor porttitor. Nunc laoreet pellentesque orci, sed ultrices tortor viverra eget. Integer ornare pellentesque suscipit. Mauris euismod leo dui, sit amet finibus tortor fermentum vel. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque efficitur tortor erat, at eleifend libero feugiat in. Pellentesque vitae ullamcorper nulla. Quisque ullamcorper facilisis turpis. Nullam blandit, mi sed pulvinar dignissim, lorem dui mattis justo, eget molestie risus enim a lorem. Aenean efficitur turpis id sem ornare, nec sagittis massa fermentum.
Nam iaculis augue vel leo volutpat mattis. Etiam et imperdiet dui. Cras egestas elementum porttitor. Aliquam neque purus, feugiat in risus in, cursus gravida quam. Donec rutrum neque massa, quis feugiat urna dignissim et. Aenean sit amet maximus dui, et aliquam ligula. Suspendisse mollis feugiat ex, eget consequat massa posuere sit amet. Donec sagittis, lacus eget imperdiet facilisis, libero leo consequat lorem, sed interdum quam nisi a metus. Proin ante mi, porttitor eget commodo eu, sollicitudin ac neque. Quisque auctor metus sed iaculis tempor. Sed pellentesque ligula interdum elit tincidunt elementum nec id velit. Nullam faucibus eu eros nec congue. Etiam hendrerit neque in velit mattis, eget scelerisque libero fringilla. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse blandit ligula sed commodo vehicula. Etiam pellentesque ex vitae porta maximus.
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="des2">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ornare vulputate nisl eget sagittis. Sed dapibus leo sed ultricies viverra. Maecenas aliquet euismod nibh in elementum. Sed eu augue eget odio luctus lacinia ac non augue. Nunc luctus iaculis tellus sit amet vestibulum. Nunc at purus felis. Cras felis tellus, consequat at tellus eget, pretium efficitur quam. Curabitur sapien nunc, lobortis a metus ut, vehicula aliquet nisi.
Aliquam pellentesque eu turpis in interdum. Nulla porttitor urna magna, a aliquam justo lobortis dignissim. Donec tincidunt, magna vel interdum bibendum, velit sem vulputate ipsum, iaculis volutpat est arcu id orci. Nulla venenatis ipsum non interdum pharetra. Nullam mattis, orci at pretium suscipit, lacus lacus sagittis dui, sit amet sollicitudin sem ipsum non enim. Aenean pulvinar leo risus, vel imperdiet nulla eleifend et. Duis vel neque sagittis, dapibus arcu et, interdum arcu. Proin at molestie elit. Vivamus aliquam porta urna et tincidunt. Integer eu odio risus. Suspendisse ornare magna ac erat maximus, quis faucibus lectus eleifend. Aliquam pellentesque sagittis lacus sed tempor. Praesent aliquet tellus non nunc euismod varius. Donec pharetra cursus nunc, nec commodo erat malesuada nec. Nam ac facilisis lorem, eget vestibulum mauris. Nam nunc odio, tempor at condimentum et, pellentesque vitae erat.
Donec mollis dolor fringilla sapien condimentum, non ultrices tortor blandit. Aenean vel massa ipsum. Ut leo nisl, vehicula nec mi elementum, varius lacinia risus. Vestibulum metus nibh, hendrerit non velit sit amet, posuere hendrerit nunc. Aenean ut felis in nisi convallis interdum. Vestibulum posuere, nulla vitae bibendum elementum, dui metus auctor ante, et ullamcorper leo turpis quis tellus. Phasellus condimentum tellus quis posuere tempus. Fusce faucibus laoreet turpis a hendrerit. Phasellus tempor consectetur urna. In dictum turpis et ligula dictum, nec placerat mi elementum. Sed interdum, eros ut finibus elementum, elit quam auctor dui, et maximus orci justo commodo tortor. Maecenas eu efficitur massa.
Vivamus at eros vel magna facilisis lacinia quis vel est. Vivamus et quam ligula. Vestibulum hendrerit scelerisque enim, eu dapibus dui pulvinar a. Vestibulum mollis tortor sit amet tempor pharetra. Nullam facilisis leo sit amet justo auctor porttitor. Nunc laoreet pellentesque orci, sed ultrices tortor viverra eget. Integer ornare pellentesque suscipit. Mauris euismod leo dui, sit amet finibus tortor fermentum vel. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque efficitur tortor erat, at eleifend libero feugiat in. Pellentesque vitae ullamcorper nulla. Quisque ullamcorper facilisis turpis. Nullam blandit, mi sed pulvinar dignissim, lorem dui mattis justo, eget molestie risus enim a lorem. Aenean efficitur turpis id sem ornare, nec sagittis massa fermentum.
Nam iaculis augue vel leo volutpat mattis. Etiam et imperdiet dui. Cras egestas elementum porttitor. Aliquam neque purus, feugiat in risus in, cursus gravida quam. Donec rutrum neque massa, quis feugiat urna dignissim et. Aenean sit amet maximus dui, et aliquam ligula. Suspendisse mollis feugiat ex, eget consequat massa posuere sit amet. Donec sagittis, lacus eget imperdiet facilisis, libero leo consequat lorem, sed interdum quam nisi a metus. Proin ante mi, porttitor eget commodo eu, sollicitudin ac neque. Quisque auctor metus sed iaculis tempor. Sed pellentesque ligula interdum elit tincidunt elementum nec id velit. Nullam faucibus eu eros nec congue. Etiam hendrerit neque in velit mattis, eget scelerisque libero fringilla. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse blandit ligula sed commodo vehicula. Etiam pellentesque ex vitae porta maximus.
</div>
```

Sorry for the poorly formatted code

Answer (score 0):

Angular recognizes #-prefixed paths as Angular paths (by default).If you want to be able to scroll to element using anchors, you can setup a function in your controller that uses $location's hash() method to set the hash.

```
.controller('appCtrl', function ($location, $scope) {
$scope.scrollTo = function (hash) {
    $location.hash(hash);
};
})
```

Then in your HTML

```
<a href="" ng-click="scrollTo('des1')">Jump to P1</a>  
<br>
<a href="" ng-click="scrollTo('des2')">Jump to P2</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I ended up making an href directive that replicates the behaviour I want.